# how to solve crashing while animating 100 of images in a view in ipad

Tags: ipad

i have one crasing issue in which in each view having animation of 100 of images.
and each time i getting memory warning,and crashing happens.

Comment: I think you're using too much memory.  I think the solution is to stop doing that.

Comment: it is a functionality to add animation in background in every view,

Comment: and in each view animation required 90 of images,

Comment: so i can't remove it from functionality.

Comment: @jatinPatel: But you're using up all available memory by doing this.  The platform doesn't afford much room in this.  You need to reevaluate your requirements and see if you can attempt to accomplish them without animating each background with a high-framerate series of images.  Think about showing key frames, and gently fade from one to another.  Or go with a low-resolution retro feel.  Or display a .mov in the background, as movie files are optimized for displaying high framerates of images.

Comment: i dont have any idea about key frame....can u please explain it..or do u have any example ....if u have then please provide me...

Comment: @jatinPatel: I have no example.  A "key frame" is a single image, from a series of images, that can represent many other frames.  Imagine a movie of one man hitting another in the face.  It may consist of 100 frames, but the "key frame" would be the one where the fist is fully contacting the face.  You can use that one frame to represent all the rest.

Comment: thankx wiil.....i'l try for the same......